# Divide Assocative array into two equal array with maximum and minmum values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this way

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [items] => 42
            [prize] => 122
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [items] => 14
            [prize] => 789
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [items] => 76
            [prize] => 1228
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [items] => 23
            [prize] => 122
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [items] => 15
            [prize] => 567
        )

)
```

From this i want to create two arrays one contains the maximum number of `items` and other contains minimum number of items

Expected output

**array1(maximum)**

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [items] => 76
            [prize] => 1228
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [items] => 42
            [prize] => 122
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [items] => 23
            [prize] => 122
        )
```

**Array 2(minmal)**

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [items] => 15
            [prize] => 567
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [items] => 23
            [prize] => 122
        )
```

`n` is length  original array

```
if(n is odd)

length firstarr=ceil(n/2);

length secondarr =n- ceil(n/2)

else 

length firstarr=secondarr=n/2
```

So how can i spli the above with maximum and minimum range of values?

Answer (score 1):

You should begin by sorting the array into order by number of items. We'll go with ascending order but it really doesn't matter that much.

There are a few different ways to achieve this. You could use `array_multisort` but I think `usort` with an anonymous function is a bit shorter and easier to follow.

If you have PHP 5.2 or earlier you'll have to move the anonymous function code into a named function and call it
that way. If you're lucky enough to have PHP 7 you can just do `return $a["items"] <=> $b["items"];` in the function.

```
$array = [["items" => 42, "prize" => 122], ["items" => 14, "prize" => 789],
          ["items" => 76, "prize" => 1228], ["items" => 23, "prize" => 122],
          ["items" => 15, "prize" => 567]];
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a["items"] < $b["items"] ? -1 : ($a["items"] > $b["items"] ? 1 : 0); });
```

Now split it into the highest and lowest values. After the `array_splice` the `$array` variable will be left containing only the
values that haven't been removed and saved into `$lowest`.

In your example the highest values were in descending order but ours are in ascending order. `array_reverse` will fix this.

```
$lowest = array_splice($array, 0, floor(count($array) / 2));
$highest = array_reverse($array);

var_dump($highest);
var_dump($lowest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `usort()` and pass the values to a callback to compare, notice the use of closure in the callback,

```
<?php

function sort_order($key, $order=1){
    if($order==1){
        return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
            return strcmp("$a[$key]","$b[$key]");
        };        
    }
    else{
        return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
            return strcmp("$b[$key]","$a[$key]");
        };  
    }

}

$minimal = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            'items' => 42,
            'prize' => 122
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            'items' => 14,
            'prize' => 789
        ),

    2 => array
        (
            'items' => 76,
            'prize' => 1228
        ),

    3 => array
        (
            'items' => 23,
            'prize' => 122
        ),

    4 => array
        (
            'items' => 15,
            'prize' => 567
        )


);


$maximum = $minimal;

usort($minimal, sort_order('items'));
usort($maximum, sort_order('items',2));
print_r($minimal);
print_r($maximum);
?>
```

Here is the fiddle : https://eval.in/539270